# Como usar o ip do cliente no file_get_contents

Tags: php

Eu fiz um script que extrai o link de qualquer vídeo que está hospedado no mp4upload, só que quando o link é extraído o ip do meu site que é identificado. 
O que eu queria sabe como que faz para o ip do cliente ser identificado ? Já tentei usar curl mas não funciono :/

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.mp4upload.com/embed-'.$_GET['id'].'.html'; //:D 
$v=@file_get_contents($url);
$source = explode("'file':", $v);
$source = explode(',', $source[1]);
$source = explode("'", $source[0]);
foreach($source as $link){$source = $link;if($source!=''){echo $video = $source;}} 

?>
```

Comment: se realmente precisa disso, talvez um proxy pode resolver, mas o proxy teria que ser o ip do seu seu cliente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em uma resposta curta **Não é possível** fazer isto via PHP, pois assim como:

- O seu navegador é *cliente* do seu servidor PHP.
- O PHP vai ser *cliente* do mp4upload.

Ou seja é o seu servidor que está pegando os dados e depois repassando para o seu navegador.

A única maneira de fazer isto seria fazer este processo no *front-end*, usando JavaScript por exemplo, mas ainda existe outro problema com isto, por segurança os navegadores bloqueiam requisições de um servidor em outro (leia sobre [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)).

Em outras palavras não tem como forçar o *mp4upload* adicionar os headers para habilitar o *CORS*, a não ser que eles tivessem uma API própria para desenvolvedores como nós usarmos (não achei nenhuma API) ou seja também **não é possíve**l fazer isto via javascript (front-end)